# Error when concatenating string date values

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading some values from a csv file. The first column of the csv is Datetime who values are like 03-10-2022 15:20, 03-10-2022 15:26, etc.

Another column named Seconds whose values are like 1200.34, 1234.23, etc

I am taking these values using csvHelper class and is as shown below :

```
    string d0 = csv.GetField<string>("DATETIME"); 
    string d5 = csv.GetField<string>("SECONDS");
```

I wanted a datetime value with milliseconds by combining these two strings such as

```
    DateTime dt = d0 + ":" + d5; // I want it like 03-10-2022 15:20:1200.34
```

What I tried is as

```
    string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff";
    DateTime dtValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here I am getting the error : System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' - dt

This is for plotting a graph in the chart. THe x axis is the datetime value with milliseconds as each tick. The value will be concatenate 2 date values with milliseconds such 03-10-2022 15:20:1200.34, 03-10-2022 15:20:1345.45, etc

I think with out using any date time function, the datetime value will be the concatenation of datetime and milliseconds.

Without use any datetime functions, I want to concatenate these 2 values like concatenating 2 string.

```
 string F = "03-10-2022 15:20";
 string S = "1200.34"
 string result = F + ":" + S; // 03-10-2022 15:20:1200.34
```

Then create a new datetime object from result like :

```
 DateTime d = new DateTime(result....);
```

so we get d whose value will be 03-10-2022 15:20:1200.34

Is this possible in C# ???

Comment: Your combined example value does not match your given format.

Comment: Is 1200.34 in milliseconds?  If so you'd want to concatenate 01.20034.  Or just parse the date time and use `AddMilliseconds`

Comment: Try Parsing Date by itself `var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(d0) ` then add the seconds
`dateTime.AddSeconds(d5)`

Answer (score 1):

parse the first part to a `DateTime`, the second to a `double` and then use [AddSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addseconds?view=net-6.0) to melt them together

```
DateTime d0 = Convert.ToDateTime(csv.GetField<string>("DATETIME")); 
DateTime complete = d0.AddSeconds( Convert.ToDouble(csv.GetField<string>("SECONDS"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ));
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F3g5XK) is a working example. After the edition you get an extra 20 minutes.

Explanation of errors:

> DateTime dt = d0 + ":" + d5;

1. here you concatenate strings and expect that the result should be of type `DateTime`. This will not work. The result will be a `string`. You would need to parse it.
2. `1200` is not a valid range for seconds which is `[0:59]`. This is one of the reasons you get a format error. The other reason is probably that the format that you use does simply not match.

> values are like 03-10-2022 15:20

and you use `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: This actually looks correct. Why did you use `Convert` instead of the `Parse` methods when you know you are dealing with strings?

Comment: @RedFox because I was confused about the format. OP writes: "values are like 03-10-2022 " and then uses the format `"MM/dd/yyyy` to parse it. so I though I let `Convert` figure out the format ;)