# How to concatenate 2 string datetime values

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How to concatenate 2 string datetime values in C# ?
I have these 2 variables as shown below :

```
string a = "03-10-2022 15:20";  --> this is the datetime value
string b = "10024.45";          --> this is just milliseconds
string c = a + ":" + b;         --> this is concatenating 2 variables to get a
                                    DateTime value with milliseconds.
```

Now the value of c is

```
c = "03-10-2022 15:20:10024.45"
```

I want to create (NOT Convert) a new DateTime value (with millisecond) from the variable c ?
Something like

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(c);
```

Don't use any datetime functions. I just want to "Concatenate" datetime var and millisecond var and create a new Datetime values with milliseconds from it.

This is for plotting the X axis of a chart. The x axis values will be like :

```
03-10-2022 15:20:10024.45, 
03-10-2022 15:25:11324.25,
03-10-2022 15:35:678.35, etc
```

Please help me to create a new datetime value with millisecond from a string ???

When I tried like this, it threw error saying that invalid data format - DateTime.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(c); // error saying invalid 
                                 // data format : DateTime.
```

Comment: What's up buddy? How's going? Just three hours ago or so you posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732961/error-when-concatenating-string-date-values where you asked about basically the same stuff but seconds instead of milliseconds. People told you that there is a method for adding seconds to a DateTime then and there. And you don't manage to make the leap and check DateTime's documentation to see if there is also an (aptly named) method for adding milliseconds to a DateTime?

Comment: What exactly is the question - your first code block seems to perform the exact task you laid out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when concatenating string date values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732961/error-when-concatenating-string-date-values)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain `DateTime` (or its representation) from `a` and `b` you can *parse*, *add* millseconds and finally format into the desired representation:

```
string a = "03-10-2022 15:20";
string b = "10024.45";

// "03-10-2022 15:20:10.02"
// if you want DateTime, not string remove the last `.ToString(...)`
var result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(a, "d-M-yyyy H:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .AddMilliseconds(double.Parse(b, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
  .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff");
```

If you have *combination* of date and milliseconds `c`, you can *split* it back into initial parts (datetime and milliseconds to add) then *parse* and *add* milliseconds:

```
// Note that we have two parts:
// Date and Time: 03-10-2022 15:20
// Milliseconds:  10024.45 
string c = "03-10-2022 15:20:10024.45";

int p = c.LastIndexOf(':');

DateTime result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(c.Substring(0, p), "d-M-yyyy H:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .AddMilliseconds(double.Parse(c.Substring(p + 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```